Is This Piece of Code Returning a Function Address?
I inherited this code. It's an embedded application that has an app and a bootloader in separate FLASH spaces. There is an API that is shared between them for some common functionality (in this case, I2C functions). However, I'm having trouble deciphering this code's intention. I've tried to simplify it here without leaving anything relevant out.
// === Type Defines ========================================================    
/// Defines the type of the bootloader API function pointer.
typedef int (* BootloaderAPICall)(uint32_t*);

// === Global Variables ====================================================    
/// The pointer to the bootloader API.
static BootloaderAPICall bootloaderAPI = NULL;

/// <bx sp : ror r7,r7>
#define BOOTLOADER_API_SIGNATURE_TAG0       (0x6847FF41)

/// <bx pc : rev r0,r0>
#define BOOTLOADER_API_SIGNATURE_TAG1       (0x784700BA)

typedef enum APIOffset_
{
    APIOffset_Tag0,
    APIOffset_Tag1,
    APIOffset_APIFunction,
    APIOffset_I2CISRAddress,
    APIOffset_I2CStatusAddress,
    APIOffset_I2CWriteBufferPtrAddress,
    APIOffset_I2CWriteBufferLengthAddress,
    APIOffset_I2CReadBufferPtrAddress,
    APIOffset_I2CReadBufferLengthAddress,
} APIOffset;

int main (void)
{
    bootloaderAPI_APIi2cInitialize();
}

int bootloaderAPI_APIi2cInitialize(void)
{
    uint32_t data[1];
    
    bootloaderAPI = scanForBootloaderEntry();
    
    // We weren't able to locate the bootloader API, so reset into the
    // bootloader and stay there.
    if (bootloaderAPI == NULL)
    {
        bootloaderAPI_applicationReboot(0);     
    }
    
    data[0] = BootloaderAPI_I2CInitialize;
    
    return bootloaderAPI(data);
}

BootloaderAPICall scanForBootloaderEntry(void)
{
    BootloaderAPICall APICall = NULL;
    
    uint32_t* address = (uint32_t*)LINK_TO_BOOTLOADER_API_ADDRESS;
    
    // Verify that the current value address have signature tags that
    // matches those of the bootloader API.
    if ((address[APIOffset_Tag0] == BOOTLOADER_API_SIGNATURE_TAG0) &&
        (address[APIOffset_Tag1] == BOOTLOADER_API_SIGNATURE_TAG1))
    {
        APICall = (BootloaderAPICall)address[APIOffset_APIFunction];   
    }
    
    return APICall;
}

I get the signature part. So ostensibly, if the two signatures in the bootloader FLASH space match the hard-coded values in the app space, scanForBootloaderEntry should retrieve the address of this function and return it to bootloaderAPI_APIi2cInitialize, which then stores this address in an array of addresses (I'm assuming so other associated addresses can be stored there)?
The issue I am having is in main.c, the call to bootloaderAPI_APIi2cInitialize has no variable to receive the returned array. Further, if I try t return something, it throws a processing  (runtime) fault. If I remove bootloaderAPI(data) from the return, it doesn't throw a fault, but I'm not sure what I'm losing by doing that. I don't think anything, but want to make sure Im not missing something. Is the processing fault likely due to the signature check failing, and thus trying to return a NULL pointer value?

"has no variable to receive the returned array" main does not receive an array; it receives a pointer (to a function).

where is main??

You talk a lot about things you do not show. What is bootloaderAPI? What is BootloaderAPICall? What is in main? How did you "try to return something"? What was this "something"? What was the caller trying to do with it? Please edit your question to show a MCVE

@Gerhardh bootloaderAPI and BootloaderAPICall are both shown in the code I posted. I have added the call from main.c.

"Is the processing fault likely due to the signature check failing, and thus trying to return a NULL pointer value?" We cannot know that. If signature check fails, scanForBootloaderEntry returns NULL, and bootloaderAPI_APIi2cInitialize should call bootloaderAPI_applicationReboot. And we don't know what that function does.

If signature is correct, bootloaderAPI variable should have non-null address of third (APIOffset_APIFunction) element from table at address LINK_TO_BOOTLOADER_API_ADDRESS. This function is then called at the end of bootloaderAPI_APIi2cInitialize with bootloaderAPI(data);, which presumably causes the crash. We cannot know why this happens. You should step through the code with debugger.
